# Gitlab Jira integration Issue transition is not happening

Tags: git, gitlab, jira, integration, smart-commits

I have integrated Jira with Gitlab, however on committing in gitlab, its not transitioning an issue from one status to another.

I have transitions as follow :
To Do (11) 
In Progress (21) 
Done (31)

As per the workflow issue can move to Done status from any other status.

I added transition ids to gitlab's jira settings and trying to commit with following commit message.

```
Updated something GITR-2 #done
```

This is adding a comment on the issue but not transitioning to Done status.

Using Gitlab Cloud edition and Jira cloud edition. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this is bothering me as well. the only thing i managed to get to work is after the merge the issue is transitioned to done, i want it to transition to in progress with first commit by writing # in-progress and #testing to move it to testing with last commit and then have it go to done after merge. did you manage to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I remember working with the same tools as you and sometimes Gitlab didn't change the state alone, but you had to change it yourself.

However, sometimes it works for me if the branch has the same name as the issue in Gitlab and Jira, but remember, identification number is enough to work, name of issue or branch doesn't care.